# How many wolves were there in the first episode?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the first episode of [*Game of Thrones*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/) the Stark family ends up with a pack of dire wolf cubs.  It's state that there are five, one for each stark child, but then John Snow found another one?  Were there five, or six, wolves?

This is made a bit confusing because you rarely see any more than one or two of the wolves at a time on screen.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Initially they found 5 wolf pups suckling on the mother, one for each legitimate Stark child

- Robb -> Greywind
- Sansa -> Lady
- Arya -> Nymeria
- Bran -> Summer
- Rickon -> Shaggydog

Afterwords, Jon Snow finds a 6th albino pup, allowing him, the illegitimate child of Eddard Stark, to have one of his own

- Jon Snow -> Ghost

Comment: On a related note, out of the 6 wolves, now only 4 survive. Right?

Comment: Correct, though Nymeria was sent away and we do not know of her fate.

Comment: We don’t know Ghost’s fate either, do we?

Comment: @unor Not that I'm aware, only that he was with Snow for a while

Comment: It is clearly hinted that Nymeria now leads a wolf pack

Comment: @kicker86 After re-watching the series recently, where was this hinted at?  Or was this hinted at in the books?

Comment: @TylerShads: Massively late comment, but in the books it is very clearly hinted she leads a pack. Arya actually dreams of her in the same way Bran dreams of Summer.

Comment: @AndrewMartin ah in the books yes, but not in the series so far.

Comment: Since they dropped Lady Stoneheart from the movies, I expect they'll drop Nymeria as well.

Answer (score 12):

The wolves that were found were 6 in number, 5 sucking milk and one albino pup.

| Master | Direwolf | Sex | Fur | Eyes | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Robb | Greywind | Male | Smoke grey | Yellow | Fierce and manhunter |
| Sansa | Lady | Female | Smoke grey | Yellow | Smallest |
| Arya | Nymeria | Female | Brownish grey | Yellow | Leader of wolf-pack |
| Bran | Summer | Male | Silver grey | Yellow | Bonded with Bran |
| Rickon | Shaggydog | Male | Black or dark | Green | Fierce and uncontrolled |
| Jon Snow | Ghost | Male | White albino | Red | Bonded with Jon |

Each direwolf embodies one of the children of Ned Stark, with each having the personalities and traits of their assigned masters. *Jon Snow* got the albino (snow like) pup as he was the bastard of Ned Stark, and not a true Stark himself. Thus, all true Starks of Winterfell come to have a direwolf of their own.